# Convert a python dictionary with sets' values to a binary dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the values are sets:

`my_dict = {1: {'a', 'b'}, 2: {'a', 'c'}, 3: {'b', 'c', 'd'}, 4: {'a'}}`

I would like to convert it to a binary dataframe where the columns are the members of the keys' sets - so for the above example, the output is as follows:

```
   a b c d
1  1 1 0 0
2  1 0 1 0
3  0 1 1 1 
4  1 0 0 0
```

How can I do it in an efficient and scalable manner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), like this:

```py
my_dict = {1: {'a', 'b'}, 2: {'a', 'c'}, 3: {'b', 'c', 'd'}, 4: {'a'}}
ser = pd.Series({k: list(v) for k, v in my_dict.items()}).str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
print(ser)
```

Comment: Cool!
How would the answer change if the input list would be like: ```my_dict = {1: {1, 2}, 2: {1, 3}, 3: {2, 3, 4}, 4: {1}}```

Comment: @IgalL I'd still go with the `str` approach, because I don't know any better way to get multiple "dummies", so simply cast each value to a str in the initial dict comprehension: `{k: [str(x) for x in v] for k, v in my_dict.items()}`. Maybe there's a better way, but I'm unaware of it.